# Generate Asp.net MVC action url from WCF service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, url, asp.net-mvc-5

I have email templates with replacable tokens and constructing of email content from WCF service, the one of token have navigating url, the url of the Asp.net MVC site.
I need to generate dynamically Asp.net MVC action url from WCF service so I can place url in email templates. 
The both application are hosted in the same web site (i.e. Under DefaultWebSite).

Right now I have set the base url in web.config app setting and construct the url by switch casing.
I am looking for batter solution by dynamically.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Right now I have set the base url in web.config app setting and construct the url by switch casing. 
Actually we are sending emails from MVC application's background thread so I am finding to generate Url from there. But I didnt find Http context there.